# Django : Message system, request

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want install a message system on my website. 
For that, I want select for each sender and recipient :

- **Username of sender - 
  Username of recipient - Last message - Date of this last exchanged message - Total number of exchanged messages.**

My models are like this :

```
class MessagePerso(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    read_at = models.DateTimeField(("read at"), null=True, blank=True)

class Conversation(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User,null=False,related_name="sender")
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User,null=False,related_name="recipient")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField(MessagePerso)
```

For now, I have this :

```
u = request.user    
Conversation.objects.filter(Q(sender=u)|Q(recipient=u)).annotate(nbMsg=Count('messages'),date=Max('messages__date_envoie')).values('sender__username','recipient__username','nbMsg','date').order_by('date')
```

**It's works but I want also the text of last message (model MessagePerso)...**

How make it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your model and get messages for specified user, for example `request.user`, you may use it like this:

`user_messages = MessageBetweenUsers.objects.filter(recepient=request.user)`

It will return all messages which were sent to current user.

If you want to get all messages related to this user, you may do it like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

all_messages = MessageBetweenUsers.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user)|Q(recepient=request.user)
```

Then you may use this queryset to get messages count, sender and recepient name etc.

Comment: Yes but I want get messages count by conversation with other user.. I'll continue to try search a solution

Comment: I modified my model (post edited) but I have one problem